# Specifying Environments in ESLint Configurations

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

From [ESLint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options):

> An environment provides predefined global variables. The available environments are:
>
> - **es6** - enable all ECMAScript 6 features except for modules (this automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 6).
> - **es2017** - adds all ECMAScript 2017 globals and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 8.
> - **es2020** - adds all ECMAScript 2020 globals and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 11.
> - **es2021** - adds all ECMAScript 2021 globals and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 12.

For **es2017**, **es2020**, **es2021** it says that they "add" new globals, but it does not say if they include globals from previous versions.

When configuring ESLint, should I include all of them or only the last one would be enough.

```json
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": "latest"
},
"env": {
  "es2021": true
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds all of the previous globals, you can check it out in their playground [here](https://eslint.org/demo#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).

`BigInt` was added in ECMAScript 2020, but if you tick ECMAScript 2021 in the playground the linter still recognizes the global.

Comment: How can you validate it in the playground? Linter shows me error whatever I choose for ECMA Version in the dropdown.

Comment: ECMA Version is for language features, for example number separators which came in ECMAScript 2021, you have checkboxes below for the environments which are for globals.